# Remote Push Notifcation for react native ios platform with pusher

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a IOS app developed with react native and has a backend api with pusher.

Any easy way to use pusher for remote push notification in ios app ?

Comment: I think they already have `react-native` support as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#react-native)

Comment: They did not support for react-native remote push notification.